# Need help calculating :Percent of production by source

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the percent of production by source in 2018 for each continent

Here is my code :

```r
df_tidy  %>%
  group_by (Country, tonnes) %>%
  select (Country, tonnes, year) %>%
  filter (Country %in% c("Africa,Americas,Asia,Europe,Oceania","tonnes")) %>%
  summarise (total.global.production = tonnes/sum(df_tidy$tonnes, na.rm=T)*100)
```

`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Country', 'tonnes' (override with `.groups` argument)". I am unsure how to fix my code since its run but I am not receiving a correct output.

Comment: I am still receiving the same output message "`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Country', 'tonnes' (override with `.groups` argument)".

Comment: That message is default behavior after `summarise()`. It is simple telling you that data were regrouped after the operation, and how you can set the default. It is not an error, warning, or anything else indicating a problem. We can guess where the issue is, but without a reproducible example it would be just that, guesswork. Can you include some sample data (in a way that is easy to copy/paste into R), and expected output?

Comment: so I changed my code to this df_tidy %>%
group_by(Country,tonnes)%>%
select(Country,tonnes,year)%>%
filter(year==2018)%>%
  summarise(total.global.production = tonnes/sum(df_tidy$tonnes, na.rm=T)*100)
df<-pivot_wider(data=df_tidy,names_from  = c("Africa","Americas","Asia","Europe","Oceania"),values_from =tonnes/sum (df_tidy$tonnes, names_sep = "_"))

Comment: @ Adam im not sure how to send a sample of my data set to you

Comment: Try giving this a read on [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Gives some hints on how to share some sample data and include it in the question.

Comment: try running : dput(df_tidy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
library(dplyr)

df_tidy  %>%
  filter(Country %in% c("Africa,Americas,Asia,Europe,Oceania","tonnes")) %>%
  group_by(Country, tonnes) %>%
  summarise(total.global.production = tonnes/sum(tonnes, na.rm=TRUE)*100)
```